# How to send all approvals in one email in Microsoft Flow?

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate, sequential-workflow

I'm sending approvals via email in a Microsoft Flow. And I need to solve a task: how to send more than one approval all in one email (daily).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

MS Flow (Power Automate) Approval connector which sends an actionable email to Approver is meant for single record processing and not for digest of requests.

We can store all the Approval requests in a list and send out an email by iterating through them every 24 hours (daily), or listing the Approval requests in email body and having “Approve All”, “Reject All”, “No Action” as responses to take action on them.

Based on the response, you can take action on items list. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2019/04/05/flow-approval-process/)

The best thing would be using mobile app to see the list of push notifications & approve them. Solve the problem by user training.

[Approve requests on your mobile device by using Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/mobile-approvals)